# Как сканировать файл txt из jar-файла

Tags: java, jar, файловый-ввод-вывод

Я хочу считать текст с файла `output.txt` и вывести его через `JOptionPane`, но, естественно, он не считывается. Не могли бы вы намекнуть, как использовать файл из jar?

Файл существует в jar файле:

[image: Jar-файл]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner my = new Scanner(new File("output.txt"));
        String result = my.nextLine();
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: При открытии jar-файла ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если текстовый файл находится в том же jar-файле, который запускается, для его чтения следует использовать не `File`, а `InputStream`, который следует получить при помощи метода [`ClassLoader::getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).  При условии, что файл `output.txt` находится в корне `jar`-файла, можно использовать `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("output.txt")` или `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/output.txt")`.

Также стоит использовать `try-with-resources` для автоматического закрытия сканера/потока ввода.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner my = new Scanner(Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("output.txt"))
        ) {
            String result = my.nextLine();
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, result);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Ещё необходимо было указать кодировку, но я догадался.

Answer (score 0):

Вытащить файл из jar-архива и положить его в папку с проектом. Лучше положить в корневой каталог, чтобы лучше было считывать от туда.

Структура jar это упакованный архив в zip формате. Поэтому читать файл из него можно только если использовать этот протокол. Можно также читать специальный URL, который поддерживает этот формат.

```
jar:file://файл.jar!/output.txt
```

Подробнее о jar файлах можно прочитать в [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html).